# Selenium text attribute returns only a partial text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Does anyone know why I get this :

`Z-In...`Instead of `Z-Index 1`

Here is my code :

```
vid = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@title,'Mytitle')]/div[1]/div[3]/span"))).text

print(vid)
```

Here is the HTML:

[image: Here is the HTML]

Comment: Post the html .

Comment: I am just wondering what you are using the `Z-Index` attribute for.

Comment: I use it on a web page with previews that I can overlap, and the Z-index is there to manage priorities, so I need them to test that there is no problem with the priorities.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't correct? Is the text collapased until you expand it at all?

Comment: Your example html code shows Z-Index 4, is this the right snippet to go with your question? Is there any styling done to the element?

Comment: Yes the example is Z-Index 4 but there are many others, how do I know if the text is collapased or not, and I didn't code the WebApp so I don't if there is any styling done to the element, how can I check that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of a couple of things:

- If your usecase is to extract the value of any attribute ideally you need to use `visibility_of_element_located()`
- As an alternative to *text* attribute you can use `get_attribute()` method.

---

### Solution

As an alternative you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
print(WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@title,'Mytitle')]/div[1]/div[3]/span[starts-with(@id, 'infoZIndex')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### Update

As an alternative you can also try setting the `expected_conditions` ato `text_to_be_present_in_element()` as follows:

```
print(WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@title,'Mytitle')]/div[1]/div[3]/span[starts-with(@id, 'infoZIndex')]"), "Index")).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Comment: Even with `visibility_of_element_located` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")` it's still the same : Z-In...

Comment: @Serinkan Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: still the same ... i don't get why he stops there and doesn't go further

Comment: @Serinkan Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: I tried your last update but it doesn't work I get a TimeoutException, what is the "Index" for ? ```(@id, 'infoZIndex')]"), "Index")) ```? And I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Serinkan `Index` is the partial text of the innerText **Z-Index 1** which you are looking to extract.

Comment: I get an empty error message ```Message:```, is it really empty or it's just hidden ?

Comment: `vid1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@title,'MyTitle')]"))).get_attribute("id")`
`try:
 print(WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@title,'MyTitle')]/div[1]/div[3]/span[@id,'infoZIndex" + vid1 +"']"), "Z-Index")).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
except TimeoutException as e:
        print(e)` I tried this with getting the Id on the upper div wich is equal to infoZIndex + Id, im pretty sure it's the right element

Comment: I checked the id of the span and the id of the ("infoZIndex" + div ID)if they were equal `infoZIndex9897724 / infoZIndex9897724`

Comment: I found why it didn't work. The Z-Index wasn't fully displayed on screen, but I don't understand because I took it from the span which has nothing to do with the displayed information. And thank you for your help.

Comment: @Serinkan Huge relief for me :) I thought from many angles about the reason. Glad you found it out.